# Sentence with conditional type III

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is this sentence written correctly?

*"If you had told me one year ago that I would be studying math, I would have said you were crazy."*

I've heard a lot of people making the sentences with such meaning without past perfect but just past simple. Like: *"If you told me one year ago that I would be studying math, I would have said you were crazy."*

Is there a difference?

Comment: "If you had told me" often gets reduced to "If you'd told me" and, further, to "If you told me." Even if someone is trying to say "If you'd told me" it will sound like "If you told me" unless assiduously enunciated.

Comment: @Robusto: Of course, there's also *Well, it's news to me. If you told me that a year ago, all I can say is I must have forgotten or I wasn't listening.* No elided ***had*** there.

Comment: @Fumble: Sure, except that is not the same usage as OP's example case.

Comment: @Robusto: I still think it's relevant. But your *specific* observation doesn't really make clear that the scope for "elision" in OP's example depends on both both the "awkwardness" of the full consonant transitions *and* the fact that ***told*** is an irregular past form. In the case of, for example, *If I had / I'd [have?!] **known** you were coming I'd've baked a cake*, no-one would dream of discarding ***had / 'd*** completely (and I suspect hardly anyone would stoop to *If I **knew** you were coming* in that "hypothetical past" context).

Comment: @Fumble: It's relevant, perhaps, but only obliquely—as is your further comment. My comment was specific to the case at hand, not intended to be applied to all related or unrelated manifestations of grammar. I stand by what I said.

Comment: @Robusto: Steady on! :) I intended no *criticism!* Simply raising a couple of related" observations which one might reasonably hope would be covered by a full *answer* (which presumably neither of us are willing to devote the time to just now).

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "type III". Perhaps your textbook or teacher gave you some list of conditionals and labeled them "type I", "type II", "type III", and so on, but -- to the best of my knowledge, at least -- there is no generally accepted numbering scheme for this. It's probably just something that one author or teacher made up for this one lesson.

Comment: @Jay: From our very own StoneyB (in ["another place!"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/172587/2637) :) *I urge you stoutly to abjure the Trinity. The nth-conditional framework is a pedagogic device which has almost nothing to do with how conditional constructions are actually used.* Sound advice indeed. There's a link to [If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals](https://academic.oup.com/eltj/article-abstract/65/1/24/629190/If-only-it-were-true-the-problem-with-the-four?redirectedFrom=fulltext) there, which I intend to peruse momentarily *(**four** conditionals?)*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There clearly is a well established numbering system, even if many of us aren't aware of it (I wasn't aware of it until I started reading ELL) and even if it is of questionable utility.  As you've probably seen by now, there are four because one of them is numbered zero (which is absurd, because the other three are almost always referred to using ordinal numerals, and "zero" isn't an ordinal).

Answer (score 1):

> If you had told me one year ago that I would be studying math, I would have said you were crazy.

Yes, it's correct (although we would be more likely to say "a year ago").

> If you told me one year ago that I would be studying math, I would have said you were crazy.

This is a more informal variant that you're probably more likely to find in AmE than in BrE.  It means exactly the same.